# Extending a left fibration along an inner horn

Tags: simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

Let $\Lambda^n_i \subseteq \Delta^n$ be an inner horn, and let $X \rightarrow \Lambda^n_i$ be a left fibration. Does there exist a left fibration $Y \rightarrow \Delta^n$ such that $X = Y \times_{\Delta^n} \Lambda^n_i$?

The only results in that direction that I am aware of are the following two lemmas from [*Left fibrations and homotopy colimits*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0704) by Heuts, Moerdijk:

> **Lemma 7.3.** Consider a pullback square of simplicial sets 
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
>     X \times_Y Z @>g>> Z\\
>     @VVV @VV p V\\
>     X @>>f> Y
> \end{CD}
>   in which $f$ is inner anodyne and $p$ is a left fibration. Then $g$ is a trivial cofibration in the Joyal model structure.
>
> **Lemma 7.4.** Let $0 < k < n$ and let $p : A \rightarrow \Lambda^n_k$ be a left fibration. Then there exists a left fibration $q : B \rightarrow \Delta^n$ and an equivalence
>   \begin{CD}
>     A @>g>> \Lambda^n_k \times_{\Delta^n} B\\
>     @VpVV @VVV\\
>     \Lambda^n_k @= \Lambda^n_k
> \end{CD}
>   in the covariant model structure over $\Lambda^n_k$.

Comment: This is a pretty natural question, and I thought about it for a while (but never found an answer either way).  Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This is shown using minimal left fibrations in Cisinski's book [Higher categories and homotopical algebra](http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/cisinski/CatLR.pdf), see the proof of Theorem 5.2.10 therein. This theorem states that the simplicial set $\mathscr{S}$, whose $n$-simplices are (essentially) the left fibrations over $\Delta^n$ with small fibres, is a quasi-category.